# Starting new threads from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a project where one thread forks 4 other threads and waits for their completion. The forking thread should have the ability to stop the forked threads at any time.
To, accomplish the same, I did something as such:

```
class ForkedThread implements Runnable {
    public boolean keepRunning = true;
    public void run() {
        while(keepRunning is true ){
        //Do the Job
        }
    }
}
```

Now since **keepRunnig** is public, it can accessed from outside and can be made false.
My Question is will I have to synchronize the usage of **keepRunning** or its fine.
Secondly, is this technique OK. Or shall I use a `ThreadPool` to do my job. 
Actually, using `ThreadPool` will increase the complexity of my code, which I didn't wanted. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply declare keepRunning as volatile, i.e.

```
public volatile boolean keepRunning = true;
```

and you'll be fine.  The volatile tells Java that the variable will be accessed by multiple threads and should be made thread-safe.  This is not really a big issue with booleans, but becomes important with references and longs.

The technique you're using is good practice.  It allows for graceful termination of the threads in question.  I would recommend you look at the new concurrency libraries (i.e. ExecutorService) of Java as they makes things like you're doing easier and safer as well.  Well worth the investment!

Comment: It very much is an issue with booleans! Otherwise the JVM is free to read `keepRunning` once, see that it's true, store it in a local cache (on the CPU, for instance) and keep reading it from there. If another thread modifies it, the JVM is under no obligation to update its cache; you could spin forever. A `volatile` prevents that. This isn't just academic; I can produce it pretty easily on my dual-core laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at ExecutorService.  It will do exactly this.